# My site toggles between OK & Error 'ASP 0115'

Tags: asp-classic

My ASP website is acting strange: 70% of the time it works normally. 30% it shows this message

> Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0115'
>
> Unexpected error
>
> /index.asp
>
> A trappable error (C0000005) occurred
>   in an external object. The script
>   cannot continue running.

Never changed anything so what is the problem?

Comment: Is this running on your local server, or is it hosted somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The ASP 0115 error (and the C0000005 error, for that matter) can correspond with a permissions issue.  Microsoft has a KB article on troubleshooting the error located here:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/194190

Answer (score 0):

More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951702.aspx) on MSDN.

Quote from the page regarding your error:

> For example, when an ASP 0115 error occurs, the browser and IIS log may display:
>
> > error 'ASP 0115'
> >  Unexpected
> >     error
> >  /[Web Name]/[ASP file
> >     name].asp
> >  A trappable error
> >     occurred in an external object. The
> >     script cannot continue running.
>
> When the error displays on the returned ASP page, you know:
>
> 1. The page that caused the problem.
> 2. An exception occurred in an external object.